# Are there many -tion words that sound like 'vision'?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, phonetics, consonants

Usually -*tion* words, such as *motion*, *education*, and *lotion*, end with a -shn sound. But *equation* ends with a sound rhyming with *vision*.

Are there many more? What might some of them be? And if the pronunciation of *equation* is a rarity for words ending in *-tion,* why did that pronunciation for it arise? I'm asking this since I am not a native English speaker and discovered this exception accidentally.

Comment: Seems both versions of pronunciation are correct: -shn and -zhn. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/equation

Comment: @ArsenY.M. and why is that ? :) since both sound different....

Comment: I am guessing that different peoples in different areas pronounced it differently, that's why. But how **-zhn** appeared and why is this word so different than the others ending in **-tion**, **-ation**, I don't know and would love to learn.

Comment: It's a [sonorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant_voicing_and_devoicing) process, changing it from [ʃ] to [ʒ], but I can't really see what is conditioning the change...

Comment: Words ending in *...tion*? Try this lot! There are 2,587 of them! http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/tion/

Comment: Your assumption is a misprision.

Comment: @Robusto nice, but we are talking about words ending with   -tion

Comment: A list would be very long indeed.

Comment: At least in the usual U.S. English pronunciation of the word, _equation_ is indeed an oddball. Interesting question.

Comment: I don't think there are any other words with *-tion* pronounced *-zhn*. And as far as I can tell nobody, not even the OED, addresses why *equation* is pronounced so oddly.

Comment: @PeterShor: A question at Quora.com asks about the unusual (for a word ending in -tion) pronunciation of _equation_, and an assistant professor of linguistics at the Free University of Tbilisi provides [this answer](http://www.quora.com/Why-is-equation-pronounced-%C9%AA%CB%88kwe%C9%AA%CA%92-%C9%99-n-and-not-with-an-unvoiced-%CA%83-as-in-the-word-nation). I'm not qualified to judge the accuracy of his explanation, but it looks to me as though he doesn't answer the question of why _equation_ rhymes with _persuasion_ and not with _situation_.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is NOT a question suitable for ELL. Those who think it is should perhaps try giving an answer to it. As someone trained in both phonetics and comparative linguistics, I have no idea what the answer is—if you think this is something any English speaker can answer, I'd say think again.

Comment: @MAKZ: In an effort to encourage others to reopen this question, I have tried to make explicit the issue of greatest interest to EL&U participants—by adding the sentence "And if the pronunciation of _equation_ is a rarity for words ending in -tion, why did that pronunciation for it arise?" to your original question. I hope that this will meet with your approval; if it doesn't, you can roll back to the earlier version of the question.

Comment: Don’t apply this rule to the word “[cation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cation)”. It’s cat-eye-on.

Comment: It might be just me, but I assume the standard algebra term ***equation*** (voiced "-zhn") refers to things like ***a=b+c*** and ***e=mc²***. When it comes to the more general context of one thing being ***equated*** with another (treated as "equal"), I'd be more than happy to switch to the unvoiced "-shn" pronuncia(-shn). The sound changes made to get from ***equate*** to that kind of ***equation*** reflect much the same shift as that to get from ***multiply*** to ***multiplication***

Comment: WS2's link is broken, for those interested here is the updated URL of the same website https://www.morewords.com/ and here is the URL showing a humungous list of words ending in -tion:  https://old.morewords.com/ends-with/tion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've read through all of the words beginning with *a* through *c* in WS2's [very useful list](https://old.morewords.com/ends-with/tion) of -*tion* words, and so far I've found that the vast majority of the words in the -*tion* family carry a *sh* sound at the beginning of the final syllable.

The main exceptions to that pattern are some words ending in -*stion* (*bastion*, *combustion*, *congestion*, *counterquestion*, *countersuggestion*, etc.) or in -*ntion* (*attention*, *contention*, *convention*, *circumvention*, etc.), which instead carry (in typical U.S. English) a *ch* sound at the beginning of the final syllable.

There is also a red herring in the form of *cation*, which is of course not a -*tion* ending at all, but a *cat[a]*- prefix attached to the root word *ion*.

Most significantly to the point of the OP's original question, none of the *a* through *c* words in WS2's list carries the sound *zh* at the beginning of the final syllable.

---

[*One hour later...*] I finished reading through all of the -*tion* entries at MoreWords.com, and the only one that—in my generic U.S. English pronunciation—has a *zh* sound at the beginning of its final syllable is *equation*. I should have taken Peter Shor's word (in a comment above) for it.

I did come across the variant spelling *kation* to go with *cation*, and I encountered one interesting exception to the -*ntion* exception that I noted earlier: To my ear, at least, *dissention* carries a *sh* sound (and not a *ch* sound) at the beginning of its final syllable; but *dissention* is a bit weird anyway because it is a variant of the more common spelling *dissension*.

Anyway, I am fairly confident that the answer to the question "How many -*tion* words are there whose last syllable sounds like the last syllable in *vision*?" is one.

Comment: Here's to brute effort!

Comment: And honorary membership in the Brute Squad...

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Thanks for updating the broken link in my answer—much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

This seems to have been a change in the last hundred years or so. [Walker's Pronouncing Dictionary](https://archive.org/details/walkerspronounc00unkngoog) from 1828, has "shun" and not "zhun", as does Webster's 1892 High School Dictionary (available via Google books).

It's possible both pronunciations were around in the 19th century, but clearly the /-ʃən/ pronunciation was considered "correct".

Since this appears to be a unique sound change that happened quite recently, it may be impossible to find a good explanation for *why* it happened.

For more evidence that this was a recent sound change, in his 1850 poem *Misunderstandings*, Lewis Carroll rhymes *equation* with *observation* and *nation*. The middle verse is as follows:

> Now  to  commence  my  argument,
>   I  shall  premise  an  observation,
>   On  which  the  greatest  kings  have  leant
>   When  striving  to  subdue a nation,
>   And  e’en  the  wretch  who  pays  no  rent
>   By  it  can  solve  a hard equation.

(Note the unusual stress on the second syllable of the verb *premise*,  which agrees with Walker's 1828 dictionary pronunciation for the verb: /priːˈmaɪz/.)

Answer (score 4):

Edit: A while after making this post, I came across the entry for the word *[transition](https://books.google.com/books/reader?id=9OsIAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_atb_hover&pg=GBS.PA636)* in Walker's *Critical Pronouncing Dictionary* (1823), which gives the pronunciation as "transizhun". The OED also lists this variant. Walker also lists a pronunciation with /ʒən/ for *abscission.* However, the explanation he gives for these irregular pronunciations does not apply to *equation*: he thinks that they are motivated by a desire to avoid having two voiceless sibilants in close succession.

The pronunciation of "abscission" with /ʒən/ seems to still be current, but the pronunciation of "transition" with /ʒən/ doesn't seem at all common today.

---

<s>As other people have mentioned, there don't seem to be any other words spelled with *-tion* but pronounced with /ʒən/ except for *equation.*</s>

The reason for the voicing in *equation* is not totally clear to me. Somewhat similar and possibly related phenomena are the voicing of /tʃ/ to /dʒ/ in various words ending in *-ich*/*-itch* (e.g. *sandwich, ostrich*; this seems to be pretty old and possibly influenced by analogy with the suffix *-age*) the voicing of /ʃ/ to /ʒ/ in words ending in *-rsion* (which seems to be fully accepted as standard now in the United States, although perhaps not so much in Britain), the voicing of  /ʃ/ to /ʒ/ in *[fission](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fission)* (possibly by analogy with *fusion*; I'm not sure if this is fully accepted as standard anywhere yet) and the voicing of /tʃ/ to /dʒ/ in *[congratulation](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congratulations)(s)* (it's not universal, but it can be heard).

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the ʒ sound in equation is phonetic over-exactitude. It may be that 
-tion after a long vowel-sound like /ei/ becomes automatically slightly vibrating. A fact, I suppose, only phoneticians were able to find out.

Daniel Jones, Pronouncing dictionary has ʒ and ʃ.

On the other hand, this is no general rule. Jones gives ʃ for nation. So I must say, I really don't understand the exceptional pronunciation of "equation". Probably only a professor of phonetics may be able to explain this.

But in my view, the problem of "equation" is of minor importance, one is understood no matter how you pronounce.

Comment: No, for me *equation* rhymes with *persuasion*, while *relation* and *nation* do not. And *relazhun* (*real Asian*?) sounds completely wrong.

Comment: @Peter Shor - The interesting question is why has equation this particular pronunciation.